# list of $L^2$ eigenfunctions and eigenvalues on a cylinder with Dirichlet boundary condition.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Using separation of variables, write down a complete list of $L^{2}$ eigenfunctions and of eigenvalues for the Laplacian on the cylinder $D\times[-1,1]$ with Dirichlet boundary conditions, where D is the 2-dim disk centered at the origin of radius 2.

Also, use this to solve the heat equation $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=\Delta u$ on this cylinder with homogeneous Dirichlet boundary condition, with initial data $u(x,y,z,0)=z$ where $z$ is the third coordinate, corresponding to the height of the cylinder.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** In cylindrical coordinates
\begin{align}
\Delta_\text{cylind} u = \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r\frac{\partial u}{\partial r} \right)+\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial \theta^2} + \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial z^2}.
\end{align}
Since you have Dirichlet boundary condition, then we see that
\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
u(2, \theta, z) = 0 & \text{for } -1\leq z \le 1 \text{ and } 0\leq \theta <2\pi,\\
u(r, \theta, \pm 1) = 0 & \text{for } 0\leq r \le 2 \text{ and } 0\leq \theta <2\pi
\end{cases}.
\end{align}

Now try separation of variables.

Comment: I’m still having trouble inducing the eigenfunctions by separating variables.